# Tag cloud example or source code for Flex

Tags: apache-flex, tags, cloud

There is such a wonderful source http://evocms-plugins.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/evocms-plugins/flash_tag_cloud_plugin/src/
but it does not get integrated into Flex. Are there other examples of an animated tag cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Carlos Carvalhar have ported wp-cumulus (its source code in your link) to Flex3.

Look here: http://code.google.com/p/tagcloud-wave/source/browse/#svn/trunk/TagcloudUI/FlexCumulusTagCloud/src